# Why ls -R does not list files of a pattern recursively?

Tags: ls

`ls -R` lists files recursively and `ls *.pdf` lists all files ending with `.pdf`. My question is why `ls` does not combine these 2 functions into 1 e.g. `ls -R \*.pdf` to look for PDF files recursively. Of course, there is `find` and others. I am curious. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `*.pdf` is expanded by the shell to all the .pdf files in the current working directory and it's not relevant to the `ls` command you expect to take `*.pdf` as to look all .pdf files in any subdirectory; to get that work you need to enable the shell (in `bash`) `globstar` option and use `**` in order to look/expand `*.pdf` in any sub-directories as well as current working directory, like below:

```
shopt -s globstar; ls -d -- **/*.pdf
```

Moreover, with using `ls -R \*.pdf`, you are looking for a single file matched literal `*.pdf` and `-R` here has no effect of looking for sub-directories (unless that `*.pdf` file is actually  a directory) and that's just used to list subdirectories recursively. with that you can use `ls` with `grep` combination to filter .pdf files.

```
ls -bR |grep '\.pdf$'
```

but this doesn't guarantee it will report only files but will report directories with same ending pattern too.

and well, as you said and were aware, best option is to using `find` command.

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf'
```

Comment: `ls -bR |grep '\.pdf$'` also won't work for files with newlines in their names. See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: @phuclv what version of `ls` do you use? with `-b` (or `-Q` or `-q`), filename with all newlines combine into single line and properly can filter. but as said `find` is best alternative and I'm aware of not parsing `ls` output thought.

Comment: Still, what you get from that `grep` is not actually the name of a file, but some encoded variant of the name, like `my\ nice\ndocument.pdf`.  Without decoding it (and knowing when it's needed to decode it), the string is useless.

Comment: ahh, if that is the concern (parse the names then), yes, absolutely that's not the right option to use it.